# How to get approximate (decimal) output for ArcCosh[e^x]

Tags: output-formatting

The specific input I'm using is ArcCosh[e^1.5400733368255632], how do I get this to give me an output in decimal form?

Comment: Capitalize the 'e'.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their responses, I seriously would've spent all day trying to figure this out.

Comment: Also, search for "E" in the documentation, and it will bring you right to the documentation page for it.

Answer (score 3):

If absolutely another way is needed:

```
Interpreter["ComputedNumber"]["ArcCosh[e^1.5400733368255632]"]
(* 2.2215292111560915 *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArcCosh[E^1.5400733368255632]
```

> ```
> 2.22153
> ```

or

```
ArcCosh[Exp[1.5400733368255632]]
```

> ```
> 2.22153
> ```

And, if you want more digits in the output

```
NumberForm[%, 16]
```

> ```
> 2.221529211156092
> ```